# Firebase Realtime Database document ordering

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am listening for new Firebase Realtime Database documents with code something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref(path)
  .orderByChild('timestamp')
  .on('child_added', snap => {
    ...
  });
```

where timestamp is set on the server with [firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#timestamp). I would like to have documents always handled in timestamp order, but I am aware that documents I add locally may arrive in the above code out of order.

I can check for and fix mis-ordered arrivals but I'd prefer not to if there is some way to have this not happen. I know about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15723418/1462337) (and answers that link to it) but I believe that applies to an earlier API without ordering methods like [`orderByChild`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#orderbychild).

I believe that I should be able to get timestamp order if I always add documents using a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) and pass `false` in the `applyLocally` argument. I am wondering if it also works to add documents from a separate Javascript context on the same client (e.g. from a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker)) without a transaction.

Will either or both of these approaches guarantee timestamp ordering? Is there any other way to achieve this? Among approaches that work, is one clearly superior or are there trade-offs among them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local estimate/latency compensation event is only fired on the client that performs the write operation. So if you perform a write operation in a different context, the original context will only see the operation when it comes from the server.

You *might* even be able to accomplish this by using two `FirebaseApp` instances, although I couldn't get that working in a quick test [here](https://jsbin.com/qalifuz/edit?js,console) myself.

Comment: I was hoping that was the case, but I wasn't sure if the library used some origin resource (like IndexedDB) that would complicate matters. Thanks!